# How to avoid processing push notifications from GCM when the app is closed

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am integrating push notifications on an app with this special behaviour:

- The app would only proccess the notification if it is open (foreground or background)

My problem comes when the user closes the app using the recent application stack (or something similar) because the onDestroy() method is not always called and the app can't delete the token from GCM. If I send a push notification at this moment the application proccesses it.

I have been looking for this issue and seems that everyone have the opposite problem, they don't receive notifications when the app is closed.

Is there anyway to configure the broadcast receiver to not wake up my application when It is closed? Or any method to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: This will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558986/gcm-how-do-i-detect-if-app-is-open-and-if-so-pop-up-an-alert-box-instead-of-nor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to achieve this,

**First Method:** Call this when you clear you app from stack,I mean in you application task,OnDestroy or OnTerminate.This will clear your Device token so you will not receive notification any more.

But you have to make sure that when you come back in your application you need to register again and send your device token to server so you can receive notification back normally.

GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);

**Second Method:**
You can use sharedpreferences, You can create it with Boolean value.You have to set value true when you start you application and false when you clear it.

Then in you GCMIntentService class you can use this preference at onMessage method.you can set condition over there that If the value is true then it will fire notification otherwise nothing will display.

In this case server will fire notification but you notification will not display in notification bar.

Hope the info will helpful for you.

Comment: If the user follows the regular flow of the application he is registered at the beggining and unregistered at the end.
The problem is that onDestroy() method is not always called (for example, when you press home button and then you close the app from the recent app stack), so any of your methods is valid in this case

Comment: You mean you want to get event when you clear application from the stack?

Comment: To get that event you can create one Application class (extends Application) then you have to call onTerminate method in that class and call your unregister method over there.It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcast receivers. register it in onStart and unregister in onStop of Activity.

If you have more than one activity and doing something from within the GCM IntentService which you want to prevent if you app isn't running then maintain a count in shared preferences and increase it in OnStart and decrease in onStop in all Activities. and when you get a GCM check if the count is positive to insure that your app is in foreground.

Comment: The application have to proccess notification when the app is in background (and the onStop() method is always called for this state)